# Override default node form submit handler

Tags: forms

I retrieve a node form and replace it's submit callback like this:

```
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'my_type', 'title' => ''));
$node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$node = my_node_handler($node, 'some_operation') // It's an object factory
  ->ekran()
  ->getEntity() // It returns a DrupalEntityWrapper
  ->value() // Node's stdClass from wrapper;

form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form_state = array();
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
$form = drupal_build_form('my_type_node_form', $form_state);

// Remove save, preview, delete, ....
remove_default_actions_from_form($form);
$form['actions']['send'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('My Button'),
  '#submit' => array('my_callback'),
  '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
  '#name' => 'name_here',
);
```

But Form API does not care what my submit callback is or even, #executes_submit_callback, It always sends the node form to node_form_submit and the node is saved.

Even changing the callback like this:

```
$form['actions']['send'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('My Button'),
  '#submit' => array('some_non_existing_function_hahaha_hohoho'),
  '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
  '#name' => 'name_here',
);
```

Will not produce an error. What's wrong here? I used entity_form(args...) for retrieving the form and this thing happened, And changed it to drupal_build_form, Still the same thing.

Also along all these, I have added:

```
  $form['#submit'] = 'die';
```

Which wont happen (not even an error about die not being callable from call_user_func...);

Answer (score 2):

Wow, The magic was using form alter along side the menu callback which created and handled the node like this:

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$f, &$fs) {
  $f['actions']['my_action'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('My Button'),
    '#submit' => array('the_submit_func_here'),
  );

dpm($f);
}
```

Notice it's not a button type but is of type "submit". I have no idea how Form API handles submits, I thought I was having issues because of FORM_ID_submit but now I have no idea what is happening?

Comment: Remember: $form['#usbmit'] is only executed when default #submit button is pressed; if another button is pressed and have its own #submit the main form #submit function will not be fired, except when de button #submit fucntin call it (I think node submit form buttons do it, calling the main submit function from the button submit function). This may be related to your problem.

Comment: @tunic The problem is always default ['#submit'] is called, and by default I mean what node module put there, doesn't matter if I change it later. But thanks for the tip it's good to know